# CSS Styling is not showing up on GitHub after being deployed

Tags: html, css, github-pages

I have now submitted a couple of projects onto my GitHub profile and for each one, none of the CSS styling appears when the project is deployed on the browser. It just shows up with plain HTML. I have researched on stack overflow for an answer and I have tried techniques advised to others and I still have the same results.

This is the link to the page https://deniseo25.github.io/Excursion/.

My HTML codee:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, inital-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-eqiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie-edge">
    <title>Excursion</title>
    <link href="./resources/css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  </head>
<body>
  <!--Landing Section-->

    <h1 class="header--main">Discover hidden places in the world around you</h1>
    <p><a class="link--cta" href="#">Download Excursion (Coming soon!)</a></p>
    <video autoplay muted loop>
      <source src="resources/videos/excursion.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

    <!--Information section-->

    <h2 class="header--secondary">Your personal travel guide</h2>
    <h4 class="header--subheader">Excursion remembers places you like, and recommends new points of interest around you.</h4>
    <p><img src="resources/images/camp.jpg" alt="camp"></p>

    <!--Coming Soon Section-->

    <p><img src="resources/images/phone.png" alt="phone"></p>
    <h4 class="header--subheader">Coming Soon for iPhone and Android</h4>
    <p><a class="link--cta" href="#">Download Excursion (Coming soon!)</a></p>

    <!--Footer Section-->

    <p class="footer-copyright">© Excursion</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please add the correct path for stylesheet

Comment: Change your path ,Look at my answer

Comment: Because in html use are specified incorrect path here is the correct one  `<link href="./Resources/CSS/style.css " type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>`

Answer (score 0):

The path you provided for CSS is not right

https://deniseo25.github.io/Excursion/resources/css/style.css 
click here it will show 404

The correct path is this 

https://deniseo25.github.io/Excursion/Resources/CSS/style.css
 Please change and it will work
So in the head section, it should be

```
<link href="./Resources/CSS/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have made that alteration on my HTML file, it loads up with some of the styling except for the images and the videos.

Comment: @DeniseO25 if it helped then please accept the answer

Comment: And you can vote for the answer you liked and which helped you

Answer (score 0):

This is because the server returns a 404(not found) while trying to load the stylesheet.

[image: Request code]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How would you go about fixing that? I have altered the link tag so its correct but I still can't get the images or videos to show up.